# java for loop storing factorial in array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

im trying to make a program that calculates factorial of 1 to 5 and store those values in an array size of 5

```
import java.util.*;
public class factorialArray
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int factorialA[] = new int[5];
        for (int i=1; i<6; i++)
        {
            int factorial = 1;
            for(int j=1; j<=i; j++)
            {
                factorial = factorial *j;
            }
            factorial = factorialA[i];
        }
        System.out.println(factorialA[3]);
    }
}
```

i want to print out third 4th index which is factorialA[3] if im understanding arrays correctly. however im getting 0. and also if i have int factorialA[]= new int[5] i get array index out of bounds could i get some help please?

Comment: yeh that worked thank you, but the array size is still a problem though i dont understand why having 1 to 5 in array size of 5 gives me out of bounds error @HighPerformanceMark

Comment: Java array indexes start from `0` (and go to `4` in a five-element-array)

Comment: @andykim run the loop till `i<5`. I have written an answer about it too, as have others

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the change the condition of the loop from

```
for (int i=1; i<6; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i=1; i<5; i++) // you could also do i=0
```

Then, this line

```
factorial = factorialA[i];
```

This doesn't make any change in your array. I suppose you intended to do

```
factorialA[i] = factorial;
```

Comment: This would only calculate the factorials up to 4

Comment: @QBrute We could make the array bigger, but as we use `i` to access the *array*, I don't think we can do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Minor correction:

```
public static void main(String [] args) { 
    int factorialA[] = new int[5]; 
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) { 
       int factorial = 1; 
       for(int j=1; j<=i+1; j++) { 
          factorial = factorial *j; 
       } 
      factorialA[i] = factorial; 
    } 
    System.out.println(factorialA[3]); 
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: at least add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is solved in the code below. The assignment factorial = factorialA[i] was not helping. You need to store the factorial value in the array which in this case will be done by factorialA[i] = factorial and also there is an indexing issue as arrays in Java is 0 index based. When your code was run, I got ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception. That is fixed in the code below. Hope this helps :-)

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    int factorialA[] = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        int factorial = 1;
        for(int j= 1; j <= i + 1; j++)
        {
            factorial = factorial * j;
        }
        factorialA[i] = factorial;
    }
    System.out.println(factorialA[3]);
}
```

Comment: this was exactly what i was looking for. i didnt think of adding 1 to i thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for this

```
public class factorialArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
        for(int i=1;i<5;i++) {
            arr[i] = factorial(i); 
        }

        for(int i=1;i<5;i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]); 
        }

    }

    public static int factorial(int number){  
          int i,fact=1;  

          for(i=1;i<=number;i++){    
              fact=fact*i;    
          }    
          return fact;   
         }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some changes which are generating `errors`.I have mentioned them in the code.

Here you are storing the `factorial of any number` at that `index` of the `array`. So if you need to store `factorials` still number `N` then you need to access `array-elements` indexed from `1-N` So you need to have Array size of `N+1`.

Another mistake you have made is here `factorial = factorialA[i];`. So here you don't manipulate value of `Array-Elements` at all which results in the initial `array` which has all elements as `0`. So you need to change the assignment order here to `factorialA[i] = factorial`.

```
import java.util.*;
public class factorialArray
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int factorialA[] = new int[6];      //Array-Size=Maximum Number+1; so here 5+1=6.
        for (int i=1; i<6; i++)
        {
            int factorial = 1;
            for(int j=1; j<=i; j++)
            {
                factorial = factorial *j;
            }
            factorialA[i] = factorial; //Here assignment should be done to the element of array.
        }
        System.out.println(factorialA[3]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to print out third 4th index which is factorialA[3] if im
>   understanding arrays correctly. however im getting 0

When you create an `int` array using `int factorialA[] = new int[5]`, the **array elements will be initialized with `0` values** which is what it is printing because you are NOT assigning the calculated factorial value to the array, so you need to correct it as shown below:

```
factorialA[i] = factorial; //assign calculated value to the array element
```

Also, array indexes start from `0`, so change the outer loop as:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
```

Comment: might want to add about the `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception

Answer (score 0):

First thing if you want factorial up to n then initialise array of length n+1. Say you want up to factorial[5], then have array of size factorial[6]. As array index starts from 0 goes up to n-1, where n is length of array.

Comment: int fact[] = new int[6];
fact[0] = 1;
for (int i=1;i<6;i++){
     fact[i] = i * fact[i-1];
}

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Factorial {

 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
        int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            arr[i] = factorial(arr[i]); 
        }

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]); 
        }

  }

  public static int factorial(int number)
  {  
          int i,fact=1;  

          for(i=1;i<=number;i++)
          {    
              fact=fact*i;    
          }    
          return fact;   
   }
```

}

@fairoz answered the problem almost correctly. They just passed the input i in the factorial class instead of arr[i], which will give the right answer